# soapclient request from php to c# web service with authentication

Tags: c#, php, soap, webservice-client

I want to execute remote function by using php soap.The web service is created by using c# .net.There must be authentication in order to call remote function.I always get unauthorized error whenever i tried to call remote function.However,when i get content of web service by using wget like this

```
wget -c --user=my_username --password=my_password http://path/to/wsdl
```

and i got this output:

```
    --2011-02-09 09:55:10--  http://path/to/wsdl
Connecting to my_ip:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to my_ip:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to my_ip:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3300 (3.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `my_webservice.asmx'

100%[====================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 3,300       --.-K/s   in 0.001s  

2011-02-09 09:55:11 (3.81 MB/s) - `my_webservice.asmx' saved [3300/3300]
```

When i use soap inorder to call remote function like this:

```
$connSoap = new SoapClient($WebServiceUrl, array('login' => $username, 
                                                 'password' => $password));
$requestOutput = $connSoap->GetVal (1, 1, 1);
```

I got this error:

```
SoapClient::SoapClient(http://path/to/wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Any comments?

Thanks in advance

Comment: according to the example you need to use : user, like  array('user' => $username, 
                                                 'password' => $password)

Comment: Hi Haim,i write the code by looking at php.net and it s written 'login' not 'user'.[link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php).   Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found alternative way to do solve this problem

I prepared and envelope xml and send request by using curl that has envelope as parameter.You can refer following code;

```
$username = "";
$password = "";
$webServiceUrl = "";

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <RemoteMethod xmlns="http://your.service.url/">
      <parameter_1>your_paramter_1</parameter_1>
      <parameter_2>your_paramter_2</parameter_2>
      ........
      <parameter_n>your_parameter_n</parameter_n>
    </RemoteMethod>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


$ch = fopen("envelope.xml", "w");
fwrite($ch, $xml);

$cmd = 'curl -d @envelope.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 " --user ' . $username . ':'.$password.' --ntlm ' . $webServiceUrl . ' > requestResult.xml';
shell_exec($cmd);
fclose($ch);
```